# How to cut down on run-time for finding dimensions of a sphere Python?

Tags: python, performance, loops, for-loop, runtime

I'm supposed to write code that prints the total number of integer solutions to the inequality x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= n, where n is a user-inputted integer that is between 1 and 2000 (inclusive), and adds all the previous numbers of solutions (E.g. n=1 returns 7 and n=2 is 19, but it returns 26 and so forth). Here is my code:

```
import math
import itertools
n = int(input("Please enter an integer between 1 and 2000: "))


def sphereCombos(radius):
  for i in range(1, radius+1):
    count = 0
    CombosList = []
    rad = int(math.sqrt(i))
    range_for_x= range(-rad, rad + 1) 
    range_for_y= range(-rad, rad + 1)
    range_for_z= range(-rad, rad + 1)
    total_perms = list(itertools.product(range_for_x, range_for_y, range_for_z))
    
  for x, y, z in total_perms:
      if x*x+ y*y + z*z <= i:
        count = count + 1
  return count

possible_combos = 0
for i in range(1, n + 1):
  possible_combos = possible_combos + sphereCombos(i)
  print(possible_combos)
```

The code works exactly as it's supposed to, but the problem is when n is set to be 2000, the program takes way too long, and I need to get it to run in 2 minutes or less. I thought using `.product()` would make it much faster than using three nested `for` loops, but that didn't end up being super true. Is there any way for me to cut down on run time?

Comment: You're iterating for every value of radius between 1 and `n` both outside and inside `sphereCombos()`. Is there any reason why you're doing this?

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark It's an inequality, so I'm going through all the solutions that'll yield anything less than n (radii between 1 and n). Let me know if that answered your question

Comment: Right, but you're doing it twice -- it seems like the `for` loop in the main function and the first `for` loop inside `sphereCombos()` are intended to handle the same thing. Is my understanding correct, and if so, are you sure that this repetition of work is necessary?

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark The first ```for``` loop inside ```sphereCombos()``` is intended to get all the values in order to create all possible permutations for the dimensions, and the ```for``` loop outside is just for the sole purpose of adding up all previous results

Comment: All you're doing in the second `for` loop is overwriting `total_perms`: only the assignment from the last iteration persists. Are you sure that the first `for` loop in `sphereCombos()` is necessary?

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark I understand now. You're totally right, the first ```for``` loop is unnecessary. I took it out, but it still doesn't run in under 2 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

The code is working because `i` is in global scope. Notice 'sphereCombos(i)'
passes `i` to radius. But the function is actually using global `i` in
`rad = int(math.sqrt(i))` and in `if x * x + y * y + z * z <= i:`

```
import math
import itertools

n = int(input("Please enter an integer between 1 and 2000: "))


def sphereCombos(radius):
    count = 0
    rad = int(math.sqrt(radius)) # Changed from i to radius
    range_for_x = range(-rad, rad + 1)
    range_for_y = range(-rad, rad + 1)
    range_for_z = range(-rad, rad + 1)
    total_perms = list(
        itertools.product(range_for_x, range_for_y, range_for_z))

    for x, y, z in total_perms:
        if x * x + y * y + z * z <= radius: # Changed from i to radius
            count = count + 1
    return count


possible_combos = 0
for i in range(1, n + 1):
    possible_combos = possible_combos + sphereCombos(i)
    print(possible_combos)
```

Comment: Tried to locate a place to use a generator function or generator expression to make it faster but could not figure out a locaton. Also, tried out map() but it was no faster either.